# Rotating a String or char clockwise by 90 degrees

Tags: java

Folks, I'm having a really hard time with rotating a Shape clockwise by 90 degrees. I'm having troubles with completing it. If there is a shape:

```
.t.
ttt
```

The method `rotateBy90()` rotates the above shape by 90 degrees clockwise, so it'll be the following output:

```
t.
tt
t.
```

THe shapes are of a `String` type. 
Here what I have and Im pretty sure Im completely doing it wrong. The method can be done by using either `char[][]`, or `char[]`, or `String[]`, or `String[][]`. Another issue is that `rotateBy90()` is a `void` method. COuld smb please help me with this rotation algorithm? Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;

public class CreateShape {

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private char dc;
    private Rotation initialPos;
    private Rotation nextPos;
    private char[][] shape = new char[height][width]; 
    String[] shapeLayout = new String[height];
    String[] rotatedArray;

public CreateShape(int height, int width, char dc)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.dc = dc;
        initialPos = Rotation.CW0;
    }

    public void rotateBy90() 
    {
        nextPos = initialPos.next();

        String newLayout = "";

        int count = 0;
        String[] newMatrixColumns= shape.split("\n");
        while (count < shape.split("\n")[0].length()) {
            for (int i = newMatrixColumns.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                newLayout += newMatrixColumns[i].charAt(count);
            }

            newLayout = newLayout + "\n";
            count++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Oops, my bad. Updated! @NicholasEason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get your approach and where your difficulties lie. I also don't get why you have so many unused fields. You may want to set your `width` and `height` fields `final`, as they shouldn't really change in this case.

Personally I think by far the easiest is to use a `char[][]`. All you have to do then is iterate your initial `char[][]` and place the element at the appropriate place in your new `char[][]`. So in your method you'd have something like

```
public void rotateBy90() 
{
    // bla bla
    char[][] tempShape = new char[width][height];

    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            tempShape[...][...] = myShape[i][j]; //I'll leave this as exercise
        }
    }

    myShape = tempShape;
}
```

Word of caution: be careful with strings. Many string operations involve creating other strings (`split`, `substring`, concatenation etc). If you do them in a long loop, you may run out of memory fairly quickly.