# How should I fit a shape into a space?

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following shape (String type);

```
..ee
e..e
```

And the following space:

```
||..
.|..
```

My method `shapeFitsAt()` determines if the given shape may be placed at the indicated row/col position.  The `row,col` indicates where the upper left
corner [block `(0,0)`] of the shape would be placed.  A shape would
not fit if one of its filled blocks would conflict with an
existing filled block in the space or would be out of bounds in
the space. "|" means block/obstacle while "." means an empty space.
So if I place the above shape into the space, it would look like this:

```
||ee
e|.e
```

Please can smb help how to approach fitting a shape into a space? Thanks in advance!

```
public class CreateSpace {

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private char[][] space = new char[height][width];
    private Shape originalShape;

    public CreateSpace(int height, int width, char[][] space, Shape shape)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.space = space;
        this.originalShape = shape;
    }
public boolean shapeFitsAt(int row, int col, Shape shape)
    {

        if(row < 0 || row >= height || col < 0 || col >= width)
            throw new FitItException("Oops! Out of bounds in CreateSpace class! Go and check!");

        else if(space[row][col] == '|' || space[row][col] == this.originalShape.getDisplayChar())
            throw new FitItException("The space position is already filled out with a wall or a character. GO CHECK CreateSpace class!");

        else
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: so, you want us write code for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853049/rotating-a-string-or-char-clockwise-by-90-degrees

Comment: Well, for each pipe in the second pattern, see if there is a dot in the first one ; move the obstacle pattern to the next position to test ; rince and repeat until satisfied.

Comment: Do I have to use loop here @OlivierCroisier?

Comment: @Lashane, just let me know how I should approach this problem. I dont want you to code

Comment: then you should use loop (probable double loop) to check whether each symbol from shape could be fit into space and throw exception if at least one symbol could not be placed

Comment: Yes, you would need 2 nested loops to test every position in your pattern grid.

Comment: Another solution would be to "linearize" the patterns into 2 bitsets (one for the shape, one for the obstacles). Put 1's where the symbols must be preserved in the shape bitset, and 0's averywhere else ; put 0's where the obstacles are, and 1's elsewhere in the "obstacle" bitset. Then AND the two bitsets, and see if the result is the same as the shape bitset. If is if, the shapes fit ; if not, at least one obstable is in the way.

Comment: I'll convert my comment to an answer to expand it and add a well-formatted example.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to "linearize" the patterns into 2 bitsets (one for the shape, one for the obstacles).

Put 1's where the symbols must be preserved in the shape bitset, and 0's averywhere else ; put 0's where the obstacles are, and 1's elsewhere in the "obstacle" bitset.

Ex:

```
..ee    -->    ..eee..e    -->    00111001
e..e

||..    -->    ||...|..    -->    00111011
.|..
```

Then AND the two bitsets, and see if the result is the same as the shape bitset. 
If is if, the shapes fit ; if not, at least one obstable is in the way.

```
    Shape : 00111001
Obstacles : 00111011
      AND : 00111001  ==  Shape bitset => OK !
```

Quick and efficient, and you can re-use the obstacle bitset to test multiple shape patterns.

Comment: THanks, @OlivierCroisier, but Im unfamiliar with bitset you've just provided

Comment: @john, `but Im unfamiliar with bitset you've just provided` - so use an Array.