# Getting IndexOutofBoundsException

Tags: java

Why here am I getting IndexOutofBoundsException 16 and Eclipse is pointing to the following code in the line:

```
 if((temp[0][0] == '.' && temp[0][height - 1] == '.') ||
```

If I pass the following String:

```
String layout =
      "..aa\n"+
      "..aa\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "aaaa\n"+
      "aaaa\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "...a\n"+
      "";
```

into the method, then Im getting that error. Could smb please help me with this? Im pretty sure Im doing smth wrong in the conditionals after the loops.**NOTE:`Layout strings` for shapes must have at least one filled block in each of `0th row`, `0th column`, `last row`, and `last column`.**
Thanks!

```
 public static Shape makeShape(String layout,char displayChar)
  {
      Shape result; 
      int height = 0;
      int width = 0;

      Scanner data = new Scanner(layout);

      while(data.hasNextLine())
      {
          String line = data.nextLine();
          width = line.length();
          height++;
      }
      char[][] temp = new char[height][width];
      Scanner data2 = new Scanner(layout);
      for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
      {

          String line = data2.nextLine();
          for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
          {
              if(line.charAt(j) != '.')
                  temp[i][j] = displayChar; 
              if(line.charAt(j) == '.')
                  temp[i][j] = line.charAt(j);

          }
      }
      data2.close();
      if((temp[0][0] == '.' && temp[0][height - 1] == '.') ||
        (temp[height - 1][0] == '.' && temp[height - 1][width - 1] == '.'))
          throw new FitItException("Empty borders!");

      result = new CreateShape(height, width, displayChar, temp);
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Text shapes, heh ? Looks like a gentleman in your class is doing the same homework : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856423/how-should-i-fit-a-shape-into-a-space/29857199#29857199

Comment: Looks the same project, @OlivierCroisier, but I have slightly different problem here.

Comment: `if((temp[0][0] == '.' && temp[0][height - 1] == '.') ||` isnt this supposed to be `if((temp[0][0] == '.' && temp[0][width - 1] == '.') ||` instead? Without looking deeply in your code, it seems this is causing your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `temp[height - 1][width - 1]` where the first index is the height and the second lookup is the width.  Now if you get these confused and use the height for the width, and the height is larger than the width, this is going to blow up.

Perhaps you intended `temp[0][width -1]`

Comment: Thanks, but to check if all edges have dots '.', should I run 2 nest loops ? @PeterLawrey

Answer (score 0):

Look closely

```
temp[0][height - 1]
```

You are using `height` in the second dimension

```
char[][] temp = new char[height][width];
```

But here, your `height` is 1st dimension and `width` is second.